# Where is ptrdiff_t defined in C?

Tags: c, types, libc, stdint

Where is `ptrdiff_t` defined in C?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's defined in `stddef.h`.

---

That header defines the integral types `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, and `wchar_t`, the functional macro `offsetof`, and the constant macro `NULL`.

Comment: Bizarrely, it's located at `linux/stddef.h` (but includes fine with `#include <stddef.h>`. It only contains definition for `NULL` (but including it gives me `ptrdiff_t`). There's some header trickery going on here which prevented me from grepping it in the first place. Can you enlighten?

Comment: And, of those, only `ptrdiff_t` and `offsetof` are not defined in any other place; the other three are defined by a number of other headers too.

Comment: @Matt: There's no definition of `ptrdiff_t` at all? Strictly speaking, a compiler doesn't have to implement anything in the header. It could get by by simply noting that if `stddef.h` is included, it will internally define `ptrdiff_t` and so on. That could be it, I don't have your version of the header available to look, though.

Comment: @Matt: the headers on Linux are an intricate construction that have to meet a large number of competing standards and requirements.  The detailed implementation of the C standard headers is entirely up to the implementation; they need not be files, even (though they most commonly are files).  To find something, use (for instance): `grep -R ptrdiff_t /usr/include`.

Comment: The real `stddef.h` is hiding under `/usr/lib/gcc/TARGET/VERSION/include` along with a number of other headers that belong to GCC (and may be GCC-version specific) rather than the C libraries.  `linux/stddef.h` is only used for kernel code (and I don't honestly see why they bother having their own copy).  You may find the `-H` switch to gcc useful for investigating this kind of question.

Comment: @Zack: Your comment could be an answer by itself. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @Zack -r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  2246 Dec  4 04:33 /usr/include/stddef.h - not hiding in /usr/lib anything, for good reason

Comment: @GoodPerson That's not a GNU-libc-based OS you've got there.  Many other C libraries do provide their own `stddef.h`, but glibc leaves it to the compiler.  In any case, if you have GCC, observe what `echo '#include <stddef.h>' | gcc -E -H -xc - > /dev/null` prints.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for `ptrdiff_t` in Visual Studio 2015 or newer, it is important to note that Microsoft is again breaking all possible conventions by not having `ptrdiff_t` defined in their version of `stddef.h` which has, since Visual Studio 2015, became part of Unversal CRT (which is part of Windows SDK).

All type definitions from `stddef.h` are now located in `vcruntime.h` -- only the `offsetof()` is still in `stddef.h`. Instead of including `stddef.h` you should include `stdint.h` which includes `vcruntime.h`.

If you need this to work cross-platform or with older versions of Visual Studio you can use something like this:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) // UCRT was introduced in VS 2015
#include <stdint.h>
#else
#include <stddef.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It is defined by the POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stddef.h.html Where the type is exactly may be implemetation-specific, but interface is stddef.h

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` in full accordance with C language standard. POSIX is completely beside the point in this case.